# R - Add decimal incremental per group

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
User | 
--------------
 1   | 
 1   | 
 2   | 
 2   |
 2   |
```

And would like to add a decimal increment per User/group like this:

```
User | value 
--------------
 1   | 0.0
 1   | 0.2
 2   | 0.0
 2   | 0.2
 2   | 0.4
```

I tried:

```
df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(value = row_number())
```

but of course row_number doesnt add any decimals. 
Furthermore I did some experiments with `seq()` but I did not achieve to always pass the respective length of the User/group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by sequence

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(User) %>%
   mutate(value = seq(0, length.out = n(), by = 0.2))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   User [2]
#   User value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   0  
#2     1   0.2
#3     2   0  
#4     2   0.2
#5     2   0.4
```

---

Or with `row_number()`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(User) %>% 
   mutate(value = 0.2 * (row_number()-1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(User = rep(c(1, 2), c(2, 3)))
```